# Can validation be added at Type level instead of individual C# property setter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

An API with multiple endpoints is exposed to consumers. In payload object, we have Nullable DateTime and Nullable Decimal properties (DateTime? & decimal?). Due to some internal technical challenges at a consumer's end, they are not able to send NULL for the DateTime? or decimal? property.

We need to support their requests and they came up with some out of bound values for the system to be considered as NULLs. Example: "1900-01-31" in DateTime? fields should be considered as NULL or 99999.00 in decimal? field should be considered NULL.

As of now, I came up with the following solution in individual property setter:

```
private DateTime? _budgetEffectiveDate;
public DateTime? BudgetEffectiveDate
{
    get
    {
        return _budgetEffectiveDate;
    }
    set
    {
        _budgetEffectiveDate = value;
        if (_budgetEffectiveDate.ToString() == "1/31/1900 12:00:00 AM")
            _budgetEffectiveDate = null;


    }
}
```

The fix is working well for them but the same changes need to be done for hundreds of C# property setters. Can there be a generic way of achieving this at the data type level without modifying each property individually?

Comment: `if (_budgetEffectiveDate.ToString() == "1/31/1900 12:00:00 AM")` **Do not do that**. This code won't work in Australia. Or lots of other places. Hell, it won't work on many PCs in the US.

Comment: Validation shouldn't be included in the type either, put validation code somewhere else

Comment: Create a custom model binder that sets the value of all `DateTime?` parameters.

Comment: Tell them to solve the non-existent "technical difficulties". `1900-01-31` is a perfectly valid date. If they want to omit that date, they should either send a `null` as the JSON standard specifies, or omit the property

Comment: https://github.com/tom-englert/AutoProperties.Fody - consider using this to write a centralised `SetValue`. Since this will impact _all_ properties then you likely want to put the classes involved in their own separate project.

Comment: `99999.00 in decimal? field should be considered NULL.` WCPGW

Answer (score 0):

How about defining your own type that extends `DateTime` by adding bounds checking? For instance (Not tested)

```
class NullableBoundedDateTime
{
    private DateTime lowerBound;
    private DateTime upperBound;
    public DateTime? dateTime
    {
        get
        {
            if (dateTime < lower || dateTime > upper)            
                return null;
            return dateTime;
        } 
        set
        {
           dateTime= value;
        }
}
```

Then refactor your code to use this class instead of `DateTime?`. Same concept can be applied to other types.

Answer (score 0):

You could have custom json converters, one for Datetimes and one for decimals which you can then use either as attributes on specific properties or add it to the 'global' configuration and this would make them be used on all types.